# Ошибка в тернарном операторе на python

Tags: python

Среда пишет, что ожидается окончание выражения. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так нельзя?

```
while a != b:
    
       a -= b if a > b else b -= a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

одновременно два присваивания можно сделать так:

```
a,b = (a-b,b) if a>b else (a,b-a)
```

Comment: Спасибо, здОрово

Answer (score 3):

Два разных присваивания в такой конструкции быть не может.
Можно только так:

```
a = a - b if a > b else b - a
```

То есть присваиваем переменной или одно, или другое.
Ваше выражение можно записать в две строки:

```
a = a - b if a > b else a
b = b - a if b > a else b
```

Comment: Спасибо, понятно